# Laravel 8 - Change default validation field "password" name

Tags: authentication, jwt, laravel-8

I'm trying to change the name of the field "password" of the variable `$credentials` that is being sent to the method `auth()->validate($credentials)`. Instead of having `$credentials['password']`, I want `$credentials['new_password']`.

Have done a lot of research and people always talk about a LoginController, saying that to do this, you have to make some modifications in this controller. But I simply can't find it in Laravel 8. Do I need to create it? Perhaps laravel 8 works a bit different? I started to work with laravel for just one week, so I'm sorry if this is a too dumb question.

Here is my code:

```
class AuthController extends Controller{

public function login(Request $request){
    $credentials = $request->all(['email','password']);

    if(auth()->validate($credentials )){
        //Some code here...
    }
}
```

Already re-declared the `getAuthPassword()` at my User model, like this:

```
public function getAuthPassword(){
    return $this->new_password;
}
```

The authentication already works with the users table column name being "new_password", but the request still needs to be sent with the field "password".

**EDIT 1: I am using JWTAuth for dealing with the authentication.**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the credential name before passing to the validator the you can do like this

```
class AuthController extends Controller{

  public function login(Request $request){
$credentials['email'] = $request->email;
$credentials['new_password'] = $request->password;
$credentials['foo'] = $request->bar;
 //some more credentials

if(auth()->validate($credentials )){
    //Some code here...
}
}
```

this may help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, what I want is to change the default field name that the validate() method uses for validating the password. If I pass $credentials['new_password'], the method returns false even if the credentials are right, because it does not recognise the index 'new_password'.

Comment: How about overwriting the validator() method. have you tried that ?